# Need help to find right Regex match pattern 

Tags: python, regex, uppercase

I can't find a working regex in **python** to split these strings:

```
CAT One | desired: CAT

DOG SILVER FOX Two | desired: DOG SILVER FOX

KING KONG | desired: KING KONG

P'OT THEN Mark First | desired P'OT THEN
```

Just stupid examples, but i need to separate words that are full uppercase from words that are only capitalized.

I could have `{1,n}` uppercase words and `{0,n}` capitalized words.

My regexs were too weird, i catch all the string or only one uppercase word..

Comment: You should **always** (nearly) specify the language you are using the regex from. It's even written in the `regex` tag description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

lines = [
    "CAT One",
    "DOG SILVER FOX Two",
    " KING KONG ",
    "P'OT THEN Mark First",
    "FOO-BAR Second FISH",
    "horsE YELLOW thirD BLUE",
    ]

for line in lines:
    print re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+(?:\W*[A-Z]+)*\b', line)
```

Output:

```
['CAT']
['DOG SILVER FOX']
['KING KONG']
["P'OT THEN"]
['FOO-BAR', 'FISH']
['YELLOW', 'BLUE']
```

Explanation:

`\b[A-Z]+` means: match one or more capital letters, but only at the start of a word. This will match "YELLOW", but not the "E" in "horsE".

`\W*[A-Z]+` means: match zero or more non-word characters, followed by one or more capital letters. This will match "'OT" or "-BAR" or " KONG".

`(?:\W*[A-Z]+)*\b` means: make a (non-capturing) group which matches zero or more times, but only at the end of a word. This will match " SILVER FOX", but not the " T" which follows it.

Comment: thanks it worked. what is ?: ? could you explain the regex a bit?

Comment: @avastreg. Glad you found it useful. I have added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A non regex solution:

```
tests = """\
CAT One
DOG SILVER FOX Two
KING KONG
P'OT THEN Mark First
""".splitlines()

isAllUppercase = lambda s: all(c.upper() == c for c in s)

from itertools import takewhile

for t in tests:
    print t
    print ' '.join(takewhile(isAllUppercase,t.split()))
    print
```

Gives:

```
CAT One
CAT

DOG SILVER FOX Two
DOG SILVER FOX

KING KONG
KING KONG

P'OT THEN Mark First
P'OT THEN
```

Comment: yes i did this in the meanwhile.. but i want to know how to do that, just in case it's impossible to find an alternative

Answer (score 0):

```
[^a-z ](?![a-z])| (?![A-Z]?[a-z])
```

Non-lower case letter or space not followed by lower case letter (so upper case letters plus digits plus symbols)

OR

space not followed by (optional Upper case letter) and lower case letter.

It isn't clear if you should pre-pend a `^` because the upper case words are always first.

```
^[^a-z ](?![a-z])| (?![A-Z]?[a-z])
```

(we are ignoring the case of space as a first character here. so no `(space)KING KONG`. If you want to include it, put a `^` after the `|`, like `^ (?![A-Z]?[a-z])`)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sort this with a negative look ahead. You scan for Uppercase NOT followed by a lowercase

```
[A-Z']+ ?[A-Z']+?(?![a-z])
```

`[A-Z']` is the range of characters you are matching, if you need more punctuation then just `'` simply add them to this range.